# Integration of secureye s-fb3k biometric machine with custom attendance software built on laravel

Tags: c++, laravel, web-applications, sdk, biometrics

I am trying to integrate secureye s-fb3k biometric machine with my custom attendance manage software which is built on laravel. But there is not enough information and step available over the internet and there official website. Need guidance on how to implement things and make it work.

I am expecting help over the integration of secureye s-fb3k biometric machine with my custom attendance manage software built on laravel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You expect help, we expect a question with a concrete problem and enough context to make it reproducible. "I don't know how to interpret the SDK documentation" and "I don't know how to integrate an SDK for a C++ program with a PHP application" are not valid questions for this site.